# bookshelf long transaction issue

Tags: javascript, promise, bookshelf.js

```
  function saveReport(t) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return new Models
        .Cycle()
        .fetchAll()
        .then((cycles) => {
          const promises = cycles.map(cycle => {
            return ReportService
              .getReportByOrgId(cycle.get('orgId'), cycle.id, undefined, t)
              .then(content => {
                let md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
                let dayNo = parseInt(Date.now() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), 10);
                var id = md5.update(cycle.id + cycle.get('orgId') + 'requestRealTimeReport' + dayNo).digest('hex');
                return new Models
                  .Report()
                  .save({
                    id: id,
                    statistics: JSON.stringify(content)
                  }, {
                    transacting: t,
                    insert: true
                  })
                  .tap(report => {
                    resolve(report);
                  })
                  .catch(console.error);
              })
              .catch(console.error);
          });
          return Promise.all(promises)
        });
    })
  }

  DbService
    .Bookshelf
    .transaction(saveReport)
    .catch(console.error);
```

When I delete this part of code:

```
.tap(report => {
    resolve(report);
})
```

it always comes with a long transaction, I just wonder what happened during this .tap() stuff how it prevent the transaction from the long transaction.

Comment: You may also want to fix up the formatting a bit so that the end of your code is not part of your question

Comment: @Doug updated the question. Good catch -- didn't even see that part.

Answer (score 0):

The `tap` portion of your code is resolving the [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) `Promise` that you declared at the top of your transaction callback.

As the [documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Bookshelf-instance-transaction) explains, you must return a `Promise` in this handler so that Bookshelf/Knex knows when you've completed everything that should be in the transaction. Note that when you `resolve` a `Promise`, you're essentially saying that the code in your promise has finished its execution successfully. Thus, the code block you are removing is an important one: it is how the transaction handler passes control back off to the Bookshelf, in a sense. Removing it puts Bookshelf in an state of waiting for something that will never happen.

I should also note that you have no `reject` call in any of your `catch` blocks. The result of this will cause problematic behavior, as Bookshelf will again never get control passed back to it if there is an error in the transaction you have specified.

Reading about the `new Promise` [documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html) on the bluebird site (or even the MDN docs) might help you get a better idea of what they're doing if my explaination did not help.